# Where can I find EMFText Documentation or examples?

Tags: model, emf, emftext

I need the EMFText documentation and some EMFText examples as weel. Where can I find these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only kind of "documentation" that I found is available at this link https://81958739-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/luismiguelpedro/curriculum-vitae/technical-reports/emftextReport.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crr-HJGhi8sNJMoilMGhZ-_S_29Pdf0CGq9vzHMqvfYQjdBx4MnGrO8AWcvB5swXXuPg63_qvVOrpAfY0k23oy4ZSgl9EiIhrzcweBIDrxVd7-yHqucNz4JcRTw1tE1vwYgTO0vjvBG7D_VXhi__o6cjL1XObkrKCdOVG0FqaHGl9sjkPW6Vc1HX4tK-hRDOQULlpwQYjQbNjP1pUU-niQYz7XbPChnnMWMnCSAbeGn3Aau8Nf64vNBT3l3Lr0YflrCM_fTOqaCMbZ-2nm1NXaeTHG5Vw%3D%3D&attredirects=3